# How can I expose a value to the global actions to share it among components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am trying to expose a value in order to share it among components:

I have this reducer:

```
import createReducer from '../../../redux/createReducer';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  currentService: 'otherservices',
};

export const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.SELECTED_SERVICE_ACTION](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      currentService: action.payload,
    };
  },
};

export default createReducer(initialState, handlers);
```

And this action:

```
import ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export const selectedServiceAction = service => ({
  type: ActionTypes.SELECTED_SERVICE_ACTION,
  payload: service,
});

export default selectedServiceAction;
```

And I have this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { DropdownV2 } from 'carbon-components-react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TableMultiSelectItems from './TableMultiSelectItems';
import { selectedServiceAction } from '../actions/cancellations';

class TableMultiselect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      itemState: 'otherservices',
    };
  }

  onChange = e => this.setState({ itemState: e.selectedItem.id });

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    // Array of dropdown's items
    const menuItems = TableMultiSelectItems(t);

    return (
      <div>
        <DropdownV2
          items={menuItems}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const wrappedComponent = connect(
  () => ({
    serviceSelected: this.state.itemState,
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    serviceSelectedHandler: serviceSelected => {
      dispatch(selectedServiceAction(serviceSelected));
    },
  }),
)(TableMultiselect);

TableMultiselect.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  serviceSelectedHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(wrappedComponent);
```

What I need from the component above is to take the value returned by the `onChange` function (`itemState: e.selectedItem.id });`) and expose it in order to grab it in another component and do something like this:

```
//other imports
import the-Action-To-Get-The-OnChange-Value from "..."

const Cancellations = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {the-Action-To-Get-The-OnChange-Value.id === 'thisID' ?
      <SLRequests/> : <SLDevices/>
    }
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

This is the first component I am trying to do with Redux, so I need some help trying to achieve what I need.

Comment: What about dispatch inside `onChange`?

Comment: @kinduser I am trying to understand Redux, that's why I am asking the question. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be accessible globally, you will have to store it inside application state (redux store). In your particular case, you want to store `e.selectedItem.id`. So besides setting the state (however this is redundant because the variable will be accessible globally).

What you need to do? Inside `onChange` function you have to dispatch the action and pass the argument.

```
onChange = (e) => this.props.dispatch(selectedServiceAction(e.selectedItem.id));
```

**Note**: To access the `dispatch` function your component has to be connected.

Then it will be catched by reducer and will be saved in store.

Comment: I think I need some more context. According to the code in my post, I can not see clearly why I have to call `this.props.dispatch(...)`

Comment: @TheUnnamed Would you consider getting familiar with redux basics? Knowledge about `dispatch` is fundamental in redux. https://redux.js.org/basics/actions